# Where to view logged results in Veins 5.1

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm somewhat new to Veins and I'm trying to record collision statistics within the sample "RSUExampleScenario" provided in the VM. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100969/how-to-get-collisions-in-veins-4-7-1) which describes what line to add to the .ini file, which I have, but I'm unable to find the "ncollisions" value in the results folder, which makes me think either I ran the wrong .ini line or am looking in the wrong place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because collision statistics take time to compute (essentially: trying to decode every transmission twice: once while considering interference by other nodes as usual, then trying again while ignoring all interference), Veins 5.1 requires you to explicitly turn collision statistics on. As discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52103375/4707703, this can be achieved by adding a line `*.**.nic.phy80211p.collectCollisionStatistics = true` to `omnetpp.ini`.

After altering the Veins 5.1 example simulation this way and running it again (e.g., by running `./run -u Cmdenv -c Default` from the command line), the `ncollisions` field in the resulting `.sca` file should now (sometimes) have non-zero values.

You can quickly verify this by running (from the command line)

```
opp_scavetool export --filter 'module("**.phy80211p") and name("ncollisions")' results/Default-\#0.sca -F CSV-R -o collisions.csv
```

The resulting `collisions.csv` should now contain a line containing (among other information) `param,,,*.**.nic.phy80211p.collectCollisionStatistics,true` (indicating that the simulation was executed with the required configuration) as well as many lines containing (among other information) `scalar,RSUExampleScenario.node[10].nic.phy80211p,ncollisions,,,1` (indicating that `node[10]` could have received one more message, had it not been for interference caused by other transmissions in the simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a list somewhere of statistics the simulation collects that I can analyze aside from "ncollisions", or a place I should look that would lead me to that? I'm having trouble navigating the documentation for Veins. Also, this is just if you already know how to do it, but is there a way to switch between synchronous/asynchronous data transfer between nodes?

Comment: @Christoph I tried running the command > opp_scavetool export [...] but I'm getting this error: "scavetool: expects version 2". The first line of the Default*.sca file is "version 3". Is there a way to update the sca file version or the scavetool? I'm using Omnet 5.7 and Oment 6_pre13.
Regards

Comment: This sounds like a very different question compared to the original one. Would you mind opening a separate question for this?